# Blade Directives not working with Spatie Addon, pulling my hair here

Tags: laravel-backpack

I've followed the readme point by point.

- I can create users / roles / permissions and assign them.
- They are also created in the DB correctly.

However, when I try to use the `@role` or `@can` blade directives, 
it's not working, it appears to always be `false`

I've tried to figure it out by myself but I'm running out of idea.  I thought it was maybe a guard issue, but I'm using the following

```
 'middleware_class' => [
    App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    Backpack\Base\app\Http\Middleware\UseBackpackAuthGuardInsteadOfDefaultAuthGuard::class,
],
```

I do not use two auth methods, only the backpack one. I did run the `make:auth` command in the past but I've since deleted all the files created by it.

the following command `dd(backpack_user()->hasRole('test'))` returns `false` which really makes me think it's a guard issue.

the table **model_has_roles** looks like the following (id 2 being my user)
[db screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB1i6.png)

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Comment: Also if I may add


when running ```{{ backpack_user()->hasPermissionTo('create_users')}}```



I get an error  **There is no permission named `create_users` for guard `web`**

Comment: Hmmm... Francois if you haven't figured this out could you please tell me what the output is anywhere inside your admin panel for the following?

Comment: ```<?php var_dump(backpack_user()); var_dump(Auth::user()); die(); ?> ```

Comment: If you're using the ```UseBackpackAuthGuardInsteadOfDefaultAuthGuard``` middleware, they should both return the same - an object based on ```App\Models\BackpackUser```, which extends ```App\User```. If you've installed Spatie\Laravel-Permission, one of them (BackpackUser or User) should have ```use HasRoles``` inside it. Most likely ```App\User```.

Comment: have you tried to clear config (php artisan config:clear)

Answer (score 1):

For my case clearing the cache fixed the issue:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it
 1. Used Backpack\Base\app\Http\Middleware\UseBackpackAuthGuardInsteadOfDefaultAuthGuard::class, in base.middleware_class array. As per the doc https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager
 2. Used directive @role('***') in the blade. @can will not work.

This was not needed in the older versions of Demo. Seems in the latest the config permissions.php has different defaults.

Answer (score 0):

if you login make sure you set the role of the user.. like this `$user->assignRole($role);`